# Recursions Javascript - Freecodecamp

Tags: javascript, recursion

beginner here. Was working through a code question on fcc and came across some javascript code I can't seem to understand.

```
function sum(arr, n) {
  // Only change code below this line
if (n <= 0) {
  return 0;
} else {
  return sum(arr, n - 1) + arr[n - 1]
}

  // Only change code above this line
}

console.log(sum([2, 3, 4, 5], 3))


// Console then spits out "9"
```

I understand how the second have of the return statement "arr[n - 1]" produces
4", but I'm unsure of how the first half "sum(arr, n - 1)" comes up with the number "5" that when added to 4, gives me the number "9" in the console.

I've narrowed it down to "sum(arr, 2)", but I can't seem to understand what the code is doing?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What don't you understand specifically?

Comment: Use the debugger and step through the code. Add some `console.log()`s and check the value of the variables. Use pen+paper and write down the steps the function does. There are only 4 elements in the array.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that **summarizes the specific problem**"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sum(arr,2)` calls the same function "sum" with the same arr parameter and a limit that's 2 instead of 3.

While the first call (inside console.log) is supposed to add a number of  parameters (3), the second call (inside the first) should add all parameters but the last one (2), which is added explicitely.

That's the point of recursion: a function that calls itself until a specific condition is met. The condition in this case is if there is no element left to be added (n<=0). Up to this all numbers appear as "arr[n-1]" in the chain of calls and are added to 0 (which is the return value in the case of the ending condition). So the actual sum is calculated as all recursive calls return one after the other.